# How to write a cron job for a python method

Tags: python

I am trying to write a cronjob to execute a method from a python file.

Is it possible to write it using a single linux shell command?

Comment: What is your OS? If you want to call just one method, the best thing to do is create a new script and either import the old one or copy-paste the relevant code (and finally call the method). For the cronjob part, `crontab -e` is the standard option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a unix OS, you would do the following.

Make your script executable with `chmod +x`

edit the crontab file using the command

```
crontab -e
```

It is a question on cron. First is add a SHEBANG line on top of your python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

add a line that resembles the one below

```
/2 * * * * /path/to/your/pythonscript.py
```

this can be used to run other scripts simply use the path to the script needed i.e.

```
/2 * * * * /path/to/script/to/run.sh
```

An explanation of the timing is below (add a slash before number to run every n timesteps, in this case every 2 minutes)

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

crontab quick reference is available at http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Yes, technically.

**The Quick-And-Dirty-And-Probably-Insecure-Way**

(File `test.py`)

```
#/usr/bin/python3
import sys

def test():
    print("You Idiot")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    globals()[sys.argv[-1]]()
```

(calling it from bash):

```
user@Hostname $ python3 test.py test
You Idiot
```

(use full path for `test.py` if you're sticking it in a cronjob)

**Somewhat Less Stupid**

Build a mapping between the functions you want to be able to call from the command line and the string you'd use to call them

```
mapping = {'test', test}

if __name__= "__main__":
     mapping[sys.argv[-1]]()
```

Comment: Just curious, why is this insecure?